# What are the "detail" and "impl" folders for?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

When messing with STL and boost, I keep seeing folders called "detail" or "impl".
What is the purpose for these folders? How do you know what belongs in here?

Are these just private implementations of interfaces?

Comment: That's all the grubby plumbing needed to get you your shiny public interfaces, yes. But look for yourself, you guessing and someone on the intertubes concurring does not really help you learn anything. (Of yourse, only look if you want to know how to implement something like that.)

Comment: You should only worry about the header files the documentation tells you to worry about.

Comment: @remyabel: sure, but it's okay to be curious (and ask). And sometimes, you do have to worry about them (like in the (infrequent) situation of a bug, and you have to dig through the guts of things).

Comment: @Cornstalks True, but that doesn't seem to be the nature of this question.

Comment: @remyabel: Perhaps we're just reading it differently, because that's how I'm understanding this question.

Comment: When you have a bunch of template code, which has interfaces and implementation code mixed in the same header files, it's hard to tell where an interface ends and an implementation starts.Seeing more of the same template code in the detail and impl folders did not help me come to the conclusion that the implementations for the public API were strictly in those folders. Because clearly they are not strictly in those folders if the entire thing is templated.

Comment: You know how you can hot-wire a car under the dash?  Well, thats kinda what the detail stuff is.  Not for you.  Use the ignition to start the car and don't mess with those wires unless you're a mechanic or a car thief.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the purpose for these folders?
>
> Are these just private implementations of interfaces?

Basically, yes.  It's where Boost and implementations of the standard library typically put stuff that isn't part of the public interface they expose, but needs to be accessible by the implementations of public interfaces.

> How do you know what belongs in here?

This is kind of a difficult question to answer because it implies that you can, from the outside looking in, come to a conclusion about where stuff should be in these directories.  You should consider these directories to be the analog of "no user servicable parts inside."  You can look in and poke around but you never know what you might find, and it could even change between versions of Boost or your C++ environment.

Using header files in these directories directly in your application is highly discouraged and will lead to non-portable code that can break by even minor upgrades to Boost or your C++ compiler.

Having said that, there is no reason you can't explore inside these directories to see how stuff works under the hood!

Comment: This actually makes sense. Thank you for the straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

The details folder is an abstraction technique for moving members that aren't in your module's public API into a sub-namespace and sub-folder to hide members developers probably don't care about, and is used for implementing the Private implementation (pimpl) design pattern; a pattern invented by one of the boost heads Herb Sutter. The pimpl pattern uses shared object models to create cross-platform pimpls that get implemented (i.e. impl) in boost using the .ipp files and forward declarations that substantially slow down the compiler. Piml is used mostly for working with hardware and OS dependent devices that rely on things like system clocks, timers, locks, threads, graphics, audio, or custom hardware, etc.

The details folder and namespace are supposed to add the benefit that they make your API cleaner and more modular but there are cleaner, simpler, more elegant, UML compliant solutions, and there are many problems with the PIMPL design pattern that make it not engineering best practice. Some of these reasons are:

- Detail folder and namespace structure takes more manual labor and time to work with.
- Piml is not UML compliant and does not work well with test driven development.
- Pimpl substantially slows down the compiler.
- The details folder and namespace creates a messy dependency diagram with coupling problems.
- The above reasons increase the cost of software development.
- Pimpl is not necessary to write portable cross-platform and cross-languages code.
- Having a clean public API is just a [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl) setup, naming convention, and file organization issue.

For a detailed explanation of why you should not use a details folder, please the [Kabuki Toolkit Application Framework](https://github.com/kabuki-starship/kabuki-toolkit/wiki/Kabuki-Toolkit-Application-Framework-Overview).